# save Yarn output to .txt file

Tags: python, file-io, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to print the output from a spark session sql query to a txt file using the following code:
rd is a list of items I am trying to query

```
    for item in rd:
        nquery = sqlquery.format(keyword = item)
        df = spark.sql(nquery)
        df.coalesce(1).write.format('txt').save("tmp/myresults.txt", header='true')
```

When I execute this using a spark submit , I get the error 'Failed to find data source - txt'. Can anyone help me how to fix it or to write the output from yarn application to a text file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `.format('text')` instead of `txt`.

Comment: that did not help. Is there a other better way of executing sql queries from a python script and getting the output of the query to be written to a csv or text file?